# How can i fix this error in python telegram bot code?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I have same error in python code when i start code

I try write telegram bot with python-telegram-bot

**THIS IS MY CODE**

```
import main as keys
import responces as R
from telegram. Ext import Updater, Command Handler, Message Handler, Filters

print("Bot started...")


def start_command(update):
    update.message.reply_text('Type Something Random to get started!')


def help_command(update):
    update.message.reply_text('If you need help! You should ask for it on Google!')


def handle_message(update):
    text = str(update.message.text).lower()
    response = R.sample_responses(text)

    update.message.reply_text(response)


def error(update, context):
    print(f"Update {update} caused error {context.error}")


def main():
    updater = Updater(keys.API_KEY, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_command))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", help_command))

    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, handle_message))

    dp.add_handler(error)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


main()
```

**THIS IS THE ERROR**

```
F:\sublime\venv\Scripts\python.exe F:/sublime/Sublime_Text_3.2.2_Build_3211_Stable/main1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\sublime\Sublime_Text_3.2.2_Build_3211_Stable\main1.py", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\sublime\Sublime_Text_3.2.2_Build_3211_Stable\main1.py", line 36, in main
    dp.add_handler(error)
  File "F:\sublime\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\dispatcher.py", line 614, in add handler
    raise TypeError(f'handler is not an instance of {Handler.__name__}')
TypeError: handler is not an instance of Handler
Bot started...
```

enter code here

Process finished with exit code 1
**Please help me to solve this error in my python**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try replacing `dp.add_handler(error)` with `dp.add_error_handler(error)` and see if the problem is solved. To inspect deeper, take a look at [this link](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/errorhandlerbot.py).

Comment: @
Rouhollah Joveini
 THANK U THAT WOKED!!!!!